# Environment variables vue js, azure kubernetes service, docker containers

Tags: docker, vue.js

I am trying to use an environment variable in a Vue.js project to store the base URL of the API used by the Vue.js app. I am able to set the variable and it works just fine in dev mode using dotenv package.

When I build a docker container, the Vue frontend doesn't hit the express JS API because the `process.env.BASE_URL` var is undefined... which is fine and expected.

When deploying to AKS I set the `BASE_URL` var in the deployment.yaml file. then I run interactive shell to print out the env variables of the Kubernetes node. `BASE_URL` is set as expected, but the front-end vue app isn't hitting the endpoint. If I hard-code the URL into the Vue project, it works as expected, but it is not working when using the `process.env.BASE_URL`

I don't really know how to debug this problem and I am out of ideas. If anyone can help I will be grateful.